# Access denied to the path for remote drive which is used to store repositories for the Visual SVN server

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I am trying to configure VisualSVN Server. When I add a remote drive path for the repository dialog box during configuration, it gives an error message saying 1access denied1. However my user account has full access to the drive and I install VisualSVN Server under my user account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I install VisualSVN Server under my user account.

VisualSVN Server's service does not run under your account. The service works under `Network Service` account, by default. The account must have access to the network share, otherwise the service can't start and you get the `Access Denied` error.

Note that the `Network Service` account represents your computer's account credentials on the network, so you must provide your COMPUTER account with access to the network share.

Must-read articles:

- [Permissions required to run VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/),
- [Storing repositories on a network share](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00022/),
- [Configuring VisualSVN Server service to run under a dedicated user account](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00024/).

PS It's recommended to leave the default value of repositories location on the first install. You can always change the location to the network share later.

Comment: exactly that is what i thought, but the thing is that the document about dedicated user show how to change it after installation, error occurs during installation since it is hard coded to use network service account by default.

Answer (score -1):

If you use a folder shared (where your svn repo is present) in a server, first try once to access the folder from 'Run' window by typing \server\sharedfolder\, enter your credentials and make sure that you can get to the repository folder. Then try configuring the SVN again.

Comment: do you mean accessing share drive from the server box? i have tried that and it works totally fine

Comment: Try to access the shared folder from the machine where you are installing SVN and not from the actual server. I have created such a setup multiple times and faced such a problem especially if a local user is logged into the SVN server machine.

Comment: i have logged in to server machine and i have access to that drive when i normally browse to folder. But when i run the configuration it says access denied